# Robospice-retrofit testing

Tags: java, android, android-testing, retrofit, robospice

I'm trying to do some unit-testing using this [robospice-retofit example](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-retrofit). The problem is i got some NullPointerException when I call the loadDataFromNetwork() method. Here's the testing code

```
public class SampleRetrofitSpiceRequestTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

private SampleRetrofitSpiceRequest sampleRetrofitSpiceRequest;

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    sampleRetrofitSpiceRequest = new SampleRetrofitSpiceRequest(
            "octo-online", "robospice");
}

public void test_loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    List contributors = sampleRetrofitSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork();
    assertTrue(contributors.size() > 0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RetrofitSpiceRequest` needs retrofit service class instance (in your case, GitHub class) to work. Call `sampleRetrofitSpiceRequest.setService(...)` with appropriate argument before calling `loadDataFromNetwork`.